# How to compare big string in PHP

Tags: php, html, string, editor, compare

Working on a Project where I need to compare 2 strings. One is from database and another is coming from post variable, so

If string is small then if($var1 == $var2) is working fine but if strings are big then this is not working fine if both are same although it is going in else condition and string is coming from PHP HTML Editor menas like a word file

Example of very very very small string which I want to save in database if post value is not equal to database value I am using 2 function also for convert string

```
mysql_real_escape_string()

nl2br(stripslashes())

<span style=\"font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; text-indent: -23.799999237060547px; font-family: Symbol; background-color: yellow;\"></span><span style=\"font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; text-indent: -23.8px; background-color: yellow; color: red;\">1</span><span style=\"font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; text-indent: -23.8px; background-color: yellow; color: red;\"><br /></span>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of when it's not working?

Comment: Is your string truncated in the DB? What does BIG mean to you? Paste some code with small strings so we can understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$var1 //string1
$var2 //string2

if(strcmp($var1, $var2))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can md5 them and then compare the md5 versions...

you keep an md5 of the string in the database and then you md5 the POST

Comment: not bad, but it also means that you don't keep the clear string in the database unless you duplicate the data; once clear and once in md5.